# python multiple list, AND func, then create new list

Tags: python, list, matrix

here's the challenge:
I have few pre defined base list
I have few funcs to find current items and return a list
I want new lists to be the AND result from pre defined lists and current lists
I then process those new current lists

I can do all of above, but my codes are hard for expansion, below is summarize of my current code, any suggestions would be helpful

```
# comment_1: user predefined lists:
base_list_fruit = ['apple','orange','banana']
base_list_meat = ['pork', 'chicken', 'beef','lamb']
base_list_vega = [] #and so on

# comment_2:custom functions to find fresh food, old food, and there may be more functions to find rotten food, etc.
def custom_find_fresh_item()
    return list_of_fresh_item()

def custom_find_old_item()
    return list_of_old_item()

# comment_3: assume this is what above functions finds, assume at any given time, also assume there can only be one type of food in either old list or fresh list, but never in both fresh and old list:
list_old = custom_find_old_item()
list_fresh = custom_find_fresh_item()

# assume this is what it finds 
>>>list_old
>>>['pork','apple']   
>>>list_fresh
>>>['lamb','banana'] 

# comment_4: define a match function to return common items exist in both list: 
def match_list(listA,listB):
    matchlist=[]
    for itemA in listA:
       for itemB in listB:
           if itemA == itemB:
                matchlist.append(itemA)
    return matchlist

# comment_5: then we have to run match_list four times:
fresh_meat_list = match_list(base_list_meat, list_fresh)
fresh_fruit_list = match_list(base_list_fruit, list_fresh)
old_meat_list = match_list(base_list_meat, list_old)
old_fruit_list = match_list(base_list_fruit, list_old)

# comment_6: some other functions to process the sorted list:
food_processor(fresh_meat_list)
food_processor(fresh_fruit_list)
food_processor(old_meat_list)
food_processor(old_fruit_list)
```

as you can see, each time I want to add more base_list and custom_find_item funcs, I'll end up hard code more match list and food_processor

is there way to create a loop to take of codes in comment_3, _5 and _6 automatically?

Comment: you're going to want to use `set` objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter, you can use `set` instead of your matching function

```
>>> s1 = set(["a","b","c"])
>>> s2 = set(["x", "y", "z", "a", "c"])
>>> s1 & s2
set(['a', 'c'])
```

As for the loop:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for base, new in product([base_list_meat, base_list_fruit], [list_fresh, list_old]):
>>>     food_processor(base, new)
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: nice, i havn't got it to work, but it certainly gave me something to read tonight at bed time. thank you.